# UITextField - bottom line programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add a bottom line to `UITextField` ...
what am I doing wrong?

```
    let emialTextField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    textField.borderStyle = .none
    textField.placeholder = "emial adress"
    let bottomline = CALayer()
    bottomline.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.height - 2, width: textField.frame.width, height: 2)
    bottomline.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    textField.layer.addSublayer(bottomline)

    return textField
}()
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?Can you share more details.

Comment: You're trying to draw a line under your text field?

Comment: One thing I see that's wrong is the way you are generating your UIColor.

The int expression `x/255` will always yield 0 for any value less than 255, and 255 if the value of x is 255. 

You need to use decimal values, like `0.0/255.0` or `128.0/255.0`.

This won't matter in your case since you're specifying a color of black. But if you're specifying black, why not use `UIColor.black`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        let emialTextField: UITextField = {
            let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 90, width: 100, height: 30))
            textField.borderStyle = .none
            textField.placeholder = "emial adress"
            let bottomline = CALayer()
            bottomline.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.height + 1, width: textField.frame.width, height: 2)
            bottomline.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 3/255, green: 4/255, blue: 5/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
            textField.layer.addSublayer(bottomline)
            return textField
        }()
        
      
        
        view.addSubview(emialTextField)
        emialTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        emialTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 90).isActive = true
        emialTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        emialTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems `textField.frame.width` is zero when executing below line of your code:

```
bottomline.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.height - 2, width: textField.frame.width, height: 2)
```

So you should add `bottomline` layer to your text field after size set for `emialTextField` via constraint or frame size.